# Why taking printscreen in games produce black screen?

Tags: windows, print-screen

Ever since I started taking screenshots using PrintScreen key I was unable to do so in games. To do that I would need to use an alternative like Fraps or Steam build-in F12 key.
I was wondering, why is that? Why does taking PrintScreen in games produce black output? Why it is unable to take an actual image? (Especially when other programs clearly can)

Thank you for an explanation

Comment: Do you have this issue in with all games / always? Or only when you play full screen? What is your OS version?

Comment: @MátéJuhász let me clarify. Ever since I started taking screenshots in any Windows OS version, full screen and so far yeah pretty much. All the games.

Comment: Are you able to do so in other full-screen applications (video,  ppt presentation)?